# CSS /HTML footer not sticking

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

I have a big problem with my footer. I searched for 1 hour now trying to find solutions. I tried everything and nothing works!

Here is an example of what my HTML structure looks like. Section, and then Footer after it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Hello World
    </header>

    <nav>
        Navigation
    </nav>

    <section>
        Hellooooo!
    </section>

    <footer id="fixed">
        Footer
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #333333;
    padding-top: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;
}

#fixed {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

section {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I made it stick to the bottom with `position: static;` but then it overlaps my content in section! how can i make it stick to bottom, and never overlap my text? I want a 30px space between section and footer if they come to close to each others.

Comment: added new answer, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

What i did is:

1. make `body { position: relative }`
2. make footer `{ position: absolute; bottom:0; left 0; }`
3. give section some room to display section { padding-bottom: 60px; }

this way the footer is always on the bottom of your body (your document) without any hack and works for IE7+ and all others. if you run the code in full page you see the footer at the bottom even if there is alot of space to travel.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  /*default*/
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  /*stick to bottom*/
  position: relative; /*make it first positioned ancestor element*/
  
  /*style*/
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #4F4F4F;
}
section {
  /*stick to bottom*/
  padding-bottom: 60px;/*give it some room to show*/
}
footer {
  /*stick to bottom*/
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /*style*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Hello World
</header>

<nav>
  Navigation
</nav>


<section>
  Cras hendrerit lacus a bibendum tristique. Suspendisse a risus elementum ipsum tristique tristique. Vivamus vitae turpis ut tortor fermentum elementum. Duis in tellus vel ligula vehicula porttitor. ivamus venenatis tellus tincidunt, cursus metus nec,
  tempor ex. Nulla efficitur nisl ut dolor pulvinar scelerisque. Cras hendrerit lacus a bibendum tristique. Suspendisse a risus elementum ipsum tristique tristique. Vivamus vitae turpis ut tortor fermentum elementum. Duis in tellus vel ligula vehicula
  porttitor. Nulla efficitur nisl ut dolor pulvinar scelerisque. Cras hendrerit lacus a bibendum tristique. Suspendisse a risus elementum ipsum tristique tristique. Vivamus vitae turpis ut tortor fermentum elementum. Duis in tellus vel ligula vehicula
  porttitor.
</section>
<footer id="fixed">
  Footer
</footer>
```